# Zero function question

Tags: functions

"The function $ g : \mathbb{R}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ satisﬁes $ g(ab) = ag(b) + bg(a)$"

For this equation, am I right in assuming that the function , $g$ ,  is a zero function?

I'm trying to prove that any input of g would equal zero, say $g(1) = 0$. I can only see this working if I assume, or prove that $g$ is a zero function.

Comment: proof by contradiction, perhaps? (I'd try to work something out but I'm rather short on time right now)

Comment: In these two cases, g(0) would equal 0 and g(1) would equal g(1) + g(1) which I'm tyring to get g(1)=0

Comment: If you have $g(1)=g(1)+g(1)$, substract $g(1)$ on both sides to get $0=g(1)$.

Comment: Well, from the equation $g(1)=g(1)+g(1)$, can you calculate what $g(1)$ is?

Comment: Oh shoot, g(1) would equal zero if you subtracted g(1) from both sides, yea?

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$
g(1)
= g(1\cdot 1)
= 1\cdot g(1)+1\cdot g(1)=2\cdot g(1)
$$
so $g(1)=0$. Moreover,
$$
g(0)=g(0\cdot 0)=0\cdot g(0)+0\cdot g(0)=0.
$$

Comment: Yea, Chris and 5xum got there, thanks.